# How to set what the new sheet button opens in Excel

Tags: excel

I made my worksheet a template and want to know how I can force it to instead of the normal blank page when I press the [new sheet button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG89p.png). This way I don't have to keep copying the same sheet every time I need to add another supplier.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing a [`Workbook.NewSheet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.newsheet) event. As with all event functions, this needs to be defined in a module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh as Object) 
  ' apply the desired elements from the template to Sh
End Sub
```

Comment: okay thank you I will try that